# Scheduled Task Never Runs unless I browse the URL manually

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I have a particular scheduled task that CF claims runs every 2 minutes. However, it either doesn't run or complete since the database changes the task is supposed to perform do not occur after each run. However if I copy the exact same URL into a browser and run the script, it works 100% of the time.

I have no clue where to start debugging. There is no IP restriction on the page.

I can see in the CF Admin that it was last run at 2:06 for example and the next run will be at 2:08. I can also see it in the scheduler.log file.

Comment: Does it require authentication at CF or DB level ?

Comment: It's just a URL. So no. Anyone can hit it technically.

Comment: Think we figured it out. We updated our certificates in IIS but apparently there is some cacerts file. They are updating them there and we'll see.

Comment: Please ensure that, you import the certs to ColdFusion/jre keystore. Otherwise, you may get handshake failures.

Comment: I saved the output to log file and got Connection Failure. Then saw in the Adobe forums someone smarter than me said something about certs and I remembered that we updated our certs from SHA-1 to 256 on the same date these stopped working.

Comment: @Leeish - Saving the output to a log file is good troubleshooting step that can help others in diagnosing scheduled task issues. You should add that last comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

We had updated our certs in IIS but didn't update our cacerts file. Once we did everything was great.

It was clear the process wasn't running when I added a line or two to email myself at the start of the task. The emails never came when the server ran the task but they did when I pinged the page. I changed the task to save the output to a log file and when I opened that up it just said "Connection Failure". This led me to some googling and some talk about certificates which made me remember that we just updated ours recently. Looking back at my emails with IT it did indeed happen on the same day that the last emails in the `mailsent.log` were sent from these scheduled tasks.